# PySpark string to timestamp conversion

Tags: string, apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp, type-conversion

How can I convert timestamp as string to timestamp in "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ" format using PySpark?

Input timestamp (string), df:

```
| col_string            |
| :-------------------- |
| 5/15/2022 2:11:06 AM  |
```

Desired output (timestamp), df:

```
| col_timestamp           |
| :---------------------- |
| 2022-05-15T2:11:06.000Z |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`to_timestamp`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp) can be used providing the optional `format` parameter.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([("5/15/2022 2:11:06 AM",)], ["col_string"])

df = df.select(F.to_timestamp("col_string", "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a").alias("col_ts"))
df.show()
# +-------------------+
# |             col_ts|
# +-------------------+
# |2022-05-15 02:11:06|
# +-------------------+

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- col_ts: timestamp (nullable = true)
```